# bootstrap add .row using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I want to make 2 column I know the structure is like this

```
.row
   .col-md-6
   .col-md-6
.row
   .col-md-6
   .col-md-6
```

but how to write it using loop in javascript?

```
    - each obj,index in obj
        if (index > 0)
             .row
                .col-md-6
```

Comment: Add for loop  to create 2 column for "col-md-6" or you want something else?

Comment: Why add a new '.row'? Rows with greater than 12 col units will simply [wrap to a new row](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping).

Comment: Are you using Jade or something ? This is not proper Javascript syntax

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty straight forward. You have to create a `nested for-loop`, which creates `x` divs with class `row` and `y` divs with class `col-md-6`.

```
var x = 2,
    y = 2,
    colClass = 'col-md-6',
    rowClass = 'row',
    rows = [],
    i, j, currentRow, currentCol;

// Variable x is the amount of rows to create.
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {

    // Create the row.
    currentRow = document.createElement('div');
    currentRow.classList.add(rowClass);

    // Variable y is the amount of columns to create for each row.
    for (j = 0; j < y; j++) {

        // Create the column.
        currentCol = document.createElement('div');
        currentCol.classList.add(colClass);

        // Append the column to the row.
        currentRow.appendChild(currentCol);
    }

    // Add the row to an array of rows.
    rows.push(currentRow);
}

// Append the rows to something, or do something else with them.
// Below practice could already be done inside the for loop, instead of rows.push(currentRow)
rows.forEach(function (row) {
    document.body.appendChild(row);
});
```